# What's ":" meaning in flutter/dart function declaration?

Tags: dart, flutter

I had a Dart trouble, the `vscode` analyzer stopped without reason.
[image: a busy cat]

I reinstall `vscode`/`dart`/`flutter`, then get packages again and nothing happens.

I found this strange non-logic problem

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  String get isWhatever:ist => "";
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  ...
}
```

I discovered I accidentally commited a `:` instead `L`, the function name was `isWhatever:ist` instead `isWhateverList`. Somebody know why?

Comment: This is likely a bug. Make an issue on dart-sdk

Comment: I will do it :)